# What exactly does the stealth kit do?

Tags: titanfall

I'm wondering what **exactly** the stealth kit in Titanfall does.  Please don't just copy and paste the in-game text like every other site on the internet does, that isn't going to help me.

I'm asking the question because its functionality (like much of Titanfall) is kind of ambiguous in the in-game description.  It says that it makes your footsteps silent; are they strictly referring to the game audio of footstep noise sent to other players?  Will my steps when rodeoing an enemy titan (that thunk thunk sound) be silent?  Does it mean that sprinting won't make me appear on the mini-map to other players (meaning that sprinting without the stealth kit **would** make me appear on the minimap)?

The internet is packed with people speculating about these things, but it seems like no one actually knows for sure (or maybe the people who **do** know just don't want to share the knowledge).

It seems like the only way to definitively answer these mechanics questions is to get a bunch of friends together (all on party chat) into a private match and rigorously test them.  I would love to do this, but sadly only two of my xbox live friends jumped on the xbone bandwagon, and they don't have Titanfall for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: +1. Here's what I know: footsteps are silent (well, according to you, I'm away from my console at the moment), the exhausts from the jump kit are invisible, sprinting doesn't cause you to appear on the mini-map. I think it's fair to say the rodeo noise will still be there.

Comment: I wonder: even if the 'physical' sounds of rodeoing are gone, won't the Titan OS still issue an "enemy pilot on hull" warning to the pilot?

Comment: Yes DooManiac, but there is a 4-5 second delay between the thunk thunk thunk and the pilot warning -- and those seconds are crucial if you want to bail out and kill the rodeoing pilot before he jumps off to face you one on one.

Answer (score 2):

This means two things:

1. If you cloak and then double jump the two blue exaust plumes won't be as visible.
2. Your footsteps make the same noise as if you are crouching, but you can sprint.

(2) is very useful in hardpoint matches when opponents are dug in, as you can sneak up on them more easily.

(1) is very useful when jumping about round titans - you'll still be pretty much invisible when double jumping to rodeo.

When you rodeo a titan they can hear your feet on the roof. They don't get the on screen warning until you pull the hatch off. As far as I can tell the kit doesn't make any difference - I've jumped on titans with the kit and they've electric smoked or jumped out *before* I've pulled the hatch.

Answer (score -2):

You will only show up on map if you shoot or are revealed by an enemy burn card.

The sound you make while riding an enemy titan is, however, unaffected.